# How to convert this PHP array to prepare an array without duplicate "terms" and combining?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to modify one PHP array and I really have hard time with it :(

```
Array ( [0] => product_category-big-savings [1] => product_category-for-men [2] => product_category-jeans [3] => brand-3-1-phillip-lim [4] => size-10 [5] => )
```

That is the array output, I want to convert it to be like this:

```
Array ( [product_category] => big-savings, for-men, jeans [brand] => 3-1-phillip-lim [size] => 10 )
```

I really can't get the hang of it. Here is what I have tried:

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    if ($v != '') {
        $arr = explode('-', $v, 2);
        $terms[] = $arr[1];
        $taxes[] = $arr[0];
    }
}
```

The first array consists of keys/values. The values are the terms I am targetting: for example:

`product_category-big-savings` is my target and I use this to split the category from its value:

```
$arr = explode('-', $v, 2);
```

Which gives me:

```
product_category ->
big-savings ->
```

And so on. How to group all product categories after that in array with `product_category` as key? and so on.

But I get an even more complicated form after that. I assume there is a simple formula that rolls this array over and convert it in the desired format. any help appreciated pleasee...

Answer (score 1):

```
list($key, $value) = explode('-', $v, 2);

if (isset($result[$key])) {
    $result[$key] .= ', ' . $value;
} else {
    $result[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Great, but I have an empty array at the end (How can I remove that). i think it is also causing an error: Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: @Marwa Aloui: it's not clear. What is "empty array at the end" And which line the notice points to?

Comment: @MarwaAloui use `array_pop($yourarray)`.

Comment: I had a $k != '' rule and it should have been $v != '' and that fixed everything :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do this instead:

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    if ($v != '') {
        $arr = explode('-', $v, 2);
        if (!isset($result[$arr[0]])){
            $result[$arr[0]] = $result[$arr[1]];
        }
        else {
            $result[$arr[0]] .= ', '.$result[$arr[1]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice try: it was completely different, and now it's entirely like mine.

Comment: Haha. I'm a little slow on the ball game today. I forgot that he wanted the comma-separated list and had nested arrays originally.